# Snowflake, cannot import partitioned parquet files to a database

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Copy of - https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008lq9RGSAY/cannot-import-partitioned-parquet-files-to-a-database

On S3 bucket I have partitioned parquet files that I want to import. Structure of the files `s3://<bucket>/data/id1=<int>/id2=<int>/file.parquet`. I have found this article as an example: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-load-terabytes-into-snowflake-speeds-feeds-and-techniques/ . But after some modification, import solution doesn't work. This is an SQL:

```
 COPY INTO PARQUET from (
    select
        NULLIF(
           regexp_replace (
           METADATA$FILENAME,
           '.*\\/id1=(.*)\\/.*',
           '\\1'),
           '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__'
         )                         as id1,
         NULLIF(
           regexp_replace (
           METADATA$FILENAME,
           '.*\\/id2=(.*)\\/.*',
           '\\1'),
           '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__'
         )                         as id2,
       $1:other as other
       from @test_parquet_stage/data/) pattern= '.*/id1=.*/id2=.*/.*';
```

I am getting "Detected recursive file loading, skipping command " . Do you have any ideas, why it doesn't work? Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

After some modifications, I was able to load data but only with one regex. as shown in article. My SQL:

```
select
     NULLIF(
       regexp_replace (
       METADATA$FILENAME,
       '.*\\/id1=(.*)\\/.*',
       '\\1'),
       '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__'
     )                         as id1,
     $1:other        as other
   from @test_parquet_stage/data/) pattern= '.*/.*';
```

But, when I add second the following error occurs:

> Numeric value '0/id2=11' is not recognized

Probably, its something related to regex, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: May I please know why you are doing     \\ in your regex      .*\\/id1=(.*)\\/.*?

Comment: \\ will be converted to \.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it for you to match `s3://<bucket>/data/id1=<int>/id2=<int>/file.parquet`:

```
.*\/id1=(.*)\/.*
```

You don't need to escape `\` if you are using it to escape other characters. In your case, `\` is used to escape `/`. So, using `\` just one time is fine.